# Is this syntactically correct for Unix Shell Script?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to replace the 20140118  with $DATE  in "Personal_20140118D_1.zip"

is  "Personal_"$DATE"D_1.zip"    syntactically correct?

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

if [ ( $FILE == "Personal_20140118D_1.zip" ) -a ( $TODAY == "Sat" ) ]; then

.....
...
.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Quotes only protect spaces from becoming word separators. You can have them in any place. So these are all equivalent as long as `a` and `b` don't contain spaces:

```
ab
"a"b
"a""b"
a"b"
a"$var"b
a${var}b
```

I suggest to use `"a${var}b"`, though since the other forms look confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the first occurrence of the date in the variable:

```
date_file=${FILE/20140118/$DATE}
```

See `man bash` for details.

Example:

```
$ date=`date +%Y%m%d`
$ file="Personal_20140118D_1.zip"
$ date_file=${file/20140118/$date}
$ echo "$date_file"
Personal_20140123D_1.zip
```